# Do real quadratic number fields with prime discriminants have odd class numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, discriminant

Using the software `SageMath` I confirmed that there is no real quadratic number field of prime discriminant $D<10^6$ with an even class number. Is this only true for small discriminants or a general truth?

Edit: Why was this question closed?

Comment: This question as well as your other question today is answered by genus theory.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer So far I don't see any answer for this question.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer But I enjoyed your open letter to the unknown Zweitkorrektor and I can feel the pain you had with him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genus theory deals with the easy piece of class groups in (mainly cyclic) Galois extensions. For quadratic extensions $K$, it goes back to Gauss, who proved, in the language of binary quadratic forms, that the ideal class of a prime ideal $P$ above an unramified prime $p$ is a square if and only if $(d_1/p) = \ldots = (d_t/p)$, where $(\cdot/\cdot)$ is the Kronecker symbol and where $d = d_1 \cdots d_t$ is the factorization of the discriminant $d$ of $K$ into prime discriminants $d_i$. This implies that for $C = Cl^+(K)$ we have $C/C^2 \simeq (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^{t-1}$. The class group Cl$^+(K)$ in the strict sense is the same as the usual class group if $d < 0$, or if $d > 0$ and the fundamental unit has norm $-1$; otherwise it is twice as big.

If the discriminant $d$ is prime, then $t = 1$, hence $C/C^2 = 1$ and therefore $C = C^2$. If squaring is an automorphism of a finite group, the group must have odd order. The same conclusion holds if $t = 2$ and the norm of the fundamental unit is positive, i.e., if $d = 2q$ for primes $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

See Flath, Introduction to Number Theory, or Harvey Cohn's Advanced number theory for proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. To see why, consider the class number formula. It says:

$\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(1-\zeta_{p}^{n})^{\chi(n)} =\epsilon^{2h}$

Where $\epsilon$ is the positive fundamental unit and $h$ is the class number. Rationalize the denominator. Then Take the square root to isolate $\epsilon^{h}$.

This can be rewritten as:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}\prod_{n \equiv \square}(1-\zeta_{p}^{n}) = \epsilon^{h}$

Where the product is taken over all square residues $n$ between 0 and $p$. Take the field norm of the entire expression. The field norm of the product is $p$, and the field norm of $\sqrt{p}$ is $-p$. The field norm of $\epsilon$ is $\pm 1$, but this won’t matter which one it is. This normed quantity looks like:

$\frac{p}{-p} = (\pm 1)^{h} = -1$

In this case, $h$ must be odd. This also tells you that $N(\epsilon)$ must also be $-1$.

Comment: I know $h_K=-1/(2 \log(\varepsilon_0)) \sum_{n=1}^{D-1} \chi_D(n) \log(\sin(\pi n/D))$ as class number formula for real quadratic number fields. What is the source of your formula?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain It is the same formula as yours, you just multiply Both sides of your equation by $2\log(\epsilon)$ and then exponentiate

Comment: I just tried to do that and obtained for each factor of the product $\sin(\pi n/D)^{-\chi_D(n)} = \Im(\zeta_{2D}^n)^{-\chi_D(n)}$ instead of your $(1-\zeta_D^n)^{-\chi_D(n)}$.

Comment: Rewrite that sin function in exponential form and factor out a root of unity from each sin. The character sum kills the exponent of the root of unity, the factor of $2i$ in the denominator, and what you’re left with is the same thing i showed you.

Comment: What I obtain is the reciprocal of what you get because I still get $(1-\zeta_D^n)^{-\chi_D(n)}$ instead of $(1-\zeta_D^n)^{\chi_D(n)}$ for the factors.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you if at this point you are still struggling to see why the class number is odd. You've arrived at the same expression I did, up to sign. I've showed you the steps. Is it not connecting yet? I probably made the mistake of forgetting a sign somewhere, but it doesn't change the overall proof and there's a simple workaround for it (take the reciprocal).

Comment: I just checked it in the case $D=5$. Your first formula should indeed be the reciprocal as I computed. But okay, I still have questions to what follows: How do you compute the root of the product? What do you mean by rationalizing the denominator?

Comment: The same way you would rationalize a square root in a fraction: you would just multiply the top and bottom by the square root to get  a rational in the denominator. In this case, you are multiplying top and bottom by the numerator in your expressions. You then use cyclotomic polynomial identity to determine the bottom must be equal to $p$. Taking the square root, you get the expression with the second product in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I did not know which fractions you were talking about. The factors stand there without numerator and denominator. But now I saw that you take half of the factors as numerator and the other half as numerator based on $n$ being a quadratic residue. Despite some small issues I could fix myself in your proof I understood the concept now. I'm missing only one last thing: How do you know that the norm of the left over product is $p$? The factors themself are not even in the field $K$, hence, we can't compute the norm factor wise.

Comment: The factors themselves are not in the field $K$ but the entire quantity is. Any automorphism composed with itself maps this quantity to itself, so it must “live” inside the quadratic field. And the norm can be computed by cyclotomic polynomials. Check out the other answer as well.